# Spring MVC - spring.ftl is causing double escaping of special characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

So I am using Spring 5.3.xx right now with a simple ftl file (i have simplified it for now)

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
<@spring.formInput path="${textInputName}" attributes='maxlength="1024"  '/>
```

with some simple free-marker settings from `context.xml`

```xml
       <property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <props>
                <prop key="datetime_format">yyyy-MM-dd</prop>
                <prop key="url_escaping_charset">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

And i have enable escaping in `web.xml`

```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I am facing an issue with **double escaping**. A simple value like `"abc"` in `input` will be render as `&quot;abc&quot;` in `input` value on a page reload.

- One is from spring when it tries to bind status

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/08bc1a050ec87cdaad6b05170c27e34d3f90cafa/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/BindStatus.java#L166-L168

- Other one is from `ftl` since the `spring.ftl` uses `#ftl output_format="HTML"` and that causes `autoEscape` below to be set to `true`

https://github.com/apache/freemarker/blob/df938ce6120ca155b87d48df97b3a6d62123b17f/src/main/java/freemarker/core/DollarVariable.java#L67-L71

Are we suppose to turn off escaping from spring from `web.xml` (which don't seem safe to me) or is it something else that I missed ?

ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; just leave the `defaultHtmlEscape` context parameter unset, and don't use some ancient Spring/JSTL version, then both JSP and FreeMarker will escape HTML form values exactly once. Especially if you don't use JSP, you have no much to fear, as `spring.formInput` is hard-wired to do HTML escaping in `spring.ftl`.

Longer version...

My experience is that, at least with Spring 5.2.3 (comes with JSTL 1.2.7), the JSP `form:input` tag escapes by default, if you don't set the `defaultHtmlEscape` context parameter at all. Also, the FreeMarker `spring.formInput` only escapes via `${...}` FreeMarker auto-escaping then, not with the JSTL binding escaping mechanism. So by default both JSP and FreeMarker escapes exactly once.

OTOH if you set `defaultHtmlEscape` to anything (`true` or `false`), one of the two (JSP or FreeMarker form support) will be broken.

But, if there's some company policy that requires you to have `defaultHtmlEscape=true`, then you can do this workaround:

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
<#assign htmlEscape = false in spring>
...
<@spring.formInput "user.name" />
```

There, `<#assign htmlEscape = false in spring>` disables the JSTL binding escaping for this response generation only, but `spring.formInput` will still do its own escaping.

**Update:** There's a caveat with `<#assign htmlEscape = false in spring>`. `<@spring.message ... />` is not affected by it, but it's affected by `defaultHtmlEscape`. If `defaultHtmlEscape` is not set, or it's set to `false` the message is not escaped. If `defaultHtmlEscape` is set to `true`, the message is escaped, and you can't avoid that (as far as you are using that macro). But there's no double escaping.

Comment: Thanks for clarification this will help, though I do wonder this shouldn't be a default behavior. but anyways thanks

Comment: @ArhamRanjha You mean `spring.htmlEscape` should default to `false`. I think that variable shouldn't even exist, as binder escaping should be always `false` in `spring.ftl`.

Comment: Anyways I did find some more observations:

if you un-set the `defaultHtmlEscape` in web.xml and then use `message` macro from `spring.ftl`. i tried to manipulate(added javascript) to the value that was going to be render by `<@spring.message` and the javascript got executed(XSS)

Here is the macro from `spring.ftl`
```ftl
<#macro message code>${springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code)?no_esc}</#macro>
```
see the `?no_esc` above, it will force `ftl` not to escape.

Comment: ...continued

```java
public String getMessage(String code) throws NoSuchMessageException {
 return getMessage(code, null, isDefaultHtmlEscape());
}
```

`getMessage` only looks at `isDefaultHtmlEscape()` which is the value of `defaultHtmlEscape` from `web.xml`.  And `htmlEscape=true/false` won't make any difference here.

Comment: @ArhamRanjha I guess the intended behavior is whatever happens if `defaultHtmlEscape` is not set at all. Not sure what `isDefaultHtmlEscape()` returns in that case though. If that shows that the intent was to allow HTML in messages, and somebody allows untrusted person to specify messages (which is rare), then they have to be cleaned from dangerous tags before hey are stored into the message source.

Comment: @ArhamRanjha Actually I tried, and by default `sping.message` it does not escape. So yeah, if you `defaultHtmlEscape` to true, the behavior changes there, and it can't be fixed. But there's no double escaping in any case. Updated my answer accordingly.